# pivot query aggregate function for bit

Tags: sql-server

We are working on task where we store results from our Tests in a database. This is our table:

```
|Path     | Date       | Result   |
|---------------------------------|
|Test1    | 01/01/2015 | True     |
|Test2    | 01/01/2015 | False    |
|Test1    | 02/02/2015 | True     |
|Test2    | 02/02/2015 | False    |
```

in this table Path is [varchar], Date is [smalldatetime] and Result [bit]. We would like to create a pivot stored procedure which will display the data in the following format:

```
|Path     | [01/01/2015] | [02/02/2015] | [03/03/2015]|
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|Test 1   | True         | True         | True        |
|Test 2   | False        | False        | False       |
```

So far we managed to get all dates:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT [Path],[Date],[Result] FROM [dbo].[Results]) AS 

[SubTable] 
pivot
(
    MAX([Result])
    FOR [Date] IN ([' + @docDates + '])
) AS [Pivot];';

EXEC @sql;
```

This selects all test dates that we need, but the tests names are repeated. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you running max on a bit column? Is there a conversion I'm not seeing? That's not valid sql.  Also, you should have brackets around every date, not just a pair of brackets around the date string.

Comment: The column names are in the table TestName, TestDate, IsPassed and in the SQL Path, Date and Result?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for the wrong column names. However here is what is working for me:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT [Path], [Date], CAST([Result] as tinyint) as [Result]  FROM [dbo].[Results]) AS [SubTable] PIVOT (Min([Result]) FOR [Date] IN ([01/01/15],[02/02/15],[03/03/15])) AS [Pivot];
```